# Voice Recording - Authentication Error - No credentials provided

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Within our application, we store voice recordings in such format.

"https://api.twilio.com#{response.uri}".chomp('.json')

e.g.

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACdbe2ee44ecf773e4ef80324e703d4ddf/Calls/CA516d5ad425160d0792491c1653a19466/Recordings/RE08917cb4f4288d95d48f451296aee005

Previously, we didn't have trouble listening to voice recordings by accessing such URLs

For some reason, it requires auth now and returns a 20003 error

Enforce HTTP Auth on Media URLs setting is disabled

Is it something changed in Twilio we are not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: If something has changed in your Twilio account, and not with your application or code, then I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: not just in my account, our clients also have the same issue. I've already contacted the support team

Comment: The support team are best placed to comment on this and let you know about your account. If you want to share a ticket number, I can follow up too.

Comment: @philnash, 8262609, thanks

Comment: I see that ticket has had some updates recently. Are things working again as expected?

Comment: @philnash, yeah, the issue was fixed, thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to hear it! Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to access the recordings without authentication then your current example URL format is incorrect. For the example URL you provided, you should use `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACdbe2ee44ecf773e4ef80324e703d4ddf/Recordings/RE08917cb4f4288d95d48f451296aee005` instead.

Comment: hey Dan, yeah, I investigated this as well but my previous format URL worked well, I don't understand why it's changed and when?